# Disable windows toast notifications for programs such as Lync

Tags: windows-7, notifications, notification-area

Is there any way to disable windows 7 toast notifications?

The toast notification which comes when there is any incoming message on Lync or any Information for other software such as McAfee  and the like... I would like to disable all such kinds of notification if possible...No notifications at all

Thanks

PS: I tried from the notification area (system tray) and tried to customize it by selecting "Hide icon and notifications" but to no affect...Any way to turn all notifications off?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other OSes that have a centralized notification system (like Mac OS or Linux distributions) Windows 7 doesn't have one, so each program uses its own code for its notifications and you'll have to manually disable them inside the program's preferences.

Comment: ok...thanks...just a thought...can we do so by using win apis maybe..?

Comment: What do you mean ? As far as I know there's no notification APIs in Windows 7 (Windows 8 may have one though), but these "notifications" are just normal windows (maybe without title bars and custom controls) so if you can code you can definitely make a program that will detect such windows and automatically close/hide them.

Comment: @kewal - You cannot disable toast notification on a system level. Each application has to implement it. Likewise its up to the application to allow you to disable it.